# Poor UDP throughput performance using UWP DatagramSocket & Socket APIs

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, uwp, udp

I have a basic C#.NET UDP server and client code and I am trying to port it to UWP. For UWP, I experimented with DatagramSocket and regular Socket class. I am seeing almost 40% packet drops on incoming UDP packets on UWP Server using DatagramSocket class. If I use UWP Sockets, I see the packet loss of around 70%. The old .NET code shows 0% packet loss.

I am thinking maybe I am not using the UWP APIs correctly and hence I am getting poor performance. Could someone guide me on how to improve UWP server performance?

Right now, all the tests are done using loop-back. UWP doesn't allow loop-back by default so I am followed the instructions mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/loopback) to enable loop-back.

The server listens for packet on 50000 port and Client code sends packets of around 60 bytes to server from 50001.

The C#.NET client code is below:

```
try
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 50001);
    IPAddress remoteIp = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(remoteIp, 50000);

    Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

    try
    {
        sender.Bind(localEP);

        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            //Thread.Sleep(1);
            // Encode the data string into a byte array. 
            string ClientReq =  "Client Request:: " + i.ToString() + " "+ Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ClientReq);

            // Send the data through the socket.  
            int sentBytes = sender.SendTo(msg, remoteEP);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}::{1} Client Request ({2} bytes):: {3}.",
            remoteEP.Address.ToString(),
            remoteEP.Port.ToString(),
            sentBytes,
            ClientReq
            );

        }

        // Release the socket.  
        sender.Close();
        //Console.ReadKey();

    }
    catch(ArgumentNullException ane)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
    }
    catch(SocketException se)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
    }

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

C#.NET Server Code:

```
byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];

IPAddress LocalIp = IPAddress.Any; //System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(LocalIp, 50000);

// Create a UDP/IP socket.  
Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp );

// Bind the socket to the local endpoint and   
// listen for incoming connections.  
try
{
    listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
    Console.WriteLine("Bind Complete");

    int messagesReceived = 0;

    while(true)
    {

        EndPoint receiveEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        int receivedBytes = listener.ReceiveFrom(buffer, ref receiveEP);

        messagesReceived++;

        IPEndPoint receiveIPEP = receiveEP as IPEndPoint;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}::{1}::{2} Client Request ({3} bytes):: {4}.",
            messagesReceived,
            receiveIPEP.Address.ToString(),
            receiveIPEP.Port.ToString(),
            receivedBytes,
            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, receivedBytes));

    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

With this above code, i see all the 10000 packets are received at server.

```
UWP DatagramSocket Code:

DgSocket = new DatagramSocket();

DgSocket.MessageReceived += SocketListener_MessageReceived;

await DgSocket.BindServiceNameAsync("50000");

private async void SocketListener_MessageReceived(DatagramSocket sender, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
{
     uint datalen = args.GetDataReader().UnconsumedBufferLength;

    DataReader reader = args.GetDataReader();
    byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
    reader.ReadBytes(dataBuffer);

    await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        lock(_lockObject)
        {
            DgPackets++;
            DgPacketList.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuffer));
        }
    });
}
```

UWP Socket Code:

```
public void SetupSimpleSocketListener()
{
    try
    {
        IPAddress LocalIp = IPAddress.Any;
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(LocalIp, 50000);
        SimpleSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp );

        byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];
        SimpleSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
        Debug.WriteLine("Bind Complete");

        SocketAsyncEventArgs sockarg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        sockarg.Completed += Sockarg_Completed;
        sockarg.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        sockarg.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        if(!SimpleSocket.ReceiveFromAsync(sockarg))
        {
            Sockarg_Completed(this, sockarg);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }    
}

private async void Sockarg_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        lock(_lockObject)
        {
            SimpleSocketPackets++;
            SimpleSocketPacketList.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesTransferred));
        }
    });

    if(e.SocketError == System.Net.Sockets.SocketError.Success)
    {
        if(!SimpleSocket.ReceiveFromAsync(e))
        {
            Sockarg_Completed(this, e);
        } 
    }
}
```

I have posted the full source code on [github](https://github.com/kaviteshsingh/experiments/tree/master/SocketPerformanceCompare):

Comment: I have tried to  connect your uwp server with [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DatagramSocket) sample, and it works fine in my side.

Comment: the problem is not of connecting to server. It is the throughput which goes down significantly when UWP Server is used instead of Console Server. Try send the data from client to server few time and you will see hige packet drops.